# fatal error: repositorie not found al momento de subir con git bash

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-bash

Actualmente eh intentado subi uno proyecto de angular a mi repositorio de github, el repositorio al que eh intentado subir es privado por lo cual su ruta es asi `https://github.com/OrganizacionNombre/NameProject` y cuando subo a mi cuenta personal que no tiene proyectos privados y todos son publicos mi ruta es asi `https://github.com/NombreUsuario/NameProject`  por lo que cuando subo a mi ruta donde el proyecto es privado me sale el siguiente error:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/OrganizacionNombre/NameProject/' not found
```

Ya agregue las credenciales de mi cuenta que esta asociada a dicha organizacion y la cual tiene acceso a ver los proyecto de ese repositorio, ese error sale cuando quiero hacer `git push origin master`

Comment: Estas seguro que tienes asociados tu repo remoto al local? que te trae con el comando `git remote -v`

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera me trae el fetch y push de la ruta  https://github.com/OrganizacionNombre/NameProject